# Upgrading python from 32 bit to 64 bit messed up pip (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-3.6, python-3.7

I upgraded python from 32-bit version to the 64-bit one, I did this by uninstalling python using add or remove programs and installing a new one from the official installer. While doing so, I also upgraded it from python 3.6 to 3.7.

Now when I try running pip I get the following error

> The code execution cannot proceed because python36.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

It didn't.

`python -m pip` works for me but I would still like to fix the original functionality.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use Python without virtual environments or containers. And you definitely should not be messing with system-level Python interpreters (you're lucky Windows doesn't rely on Python for any system utilities).

Comment: What does `where pip` display?  Does the output make sense? (If there is a directory in the `where` output that reflects Python 3.6, you'll want to remove that from your `%PATH%`).

Comment: @jedwards thanks. Though the location made sense I still checked it and found out `pip.exe` was created earlier than when it's supposed to be. I uninstalled, deleted the whole directory and reinstalled python and this time it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me too and I didn't get any solution to it. But when I installed Python 3.7 then I did not face any problem. And the pip too was working.

Maybe there was an error in the bindings of Python 3.6.